# Delegates and events in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

My application is a wizard , it contains many pages. On the click of next button i load different user controls .I I am doing this by creating object of one user control in another user control . But i want to do it using delegates and events . Can u please help me .Thanx a lot in advanced

Regards
Sanchaita

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly used method to do so is via LoadControl method.